# ASP.NET MVC routing not working with IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC web app. The app works perfectly on the development server, and all the routes (which are extension less) work fine. But problems began after trying to deploy this app onto IIS 7.5.

The only page that loads is the index, everything after that is just 404's (from IIS). I have found that if I add a dot (.) to the end of the URL, the error is not from IIS anymore, but from ASP, so my guess is that IIS it's not interpreting extension less routes properly.

Here's a list of things I have tried:

- Using the Microsoft hotfix (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368), but it just says it's not applicable (I have Windows 7 S1)
- Adding to Web.config `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`
- Adding 
  `<modules>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>`
- Running IIS on **Integrated** mode AND **Classic** mode.
- Adding a **Wildcard Script Map** to IIS.
- Made sure all IIS features were enabled.
- Tried both the **Published** app from Visual Studio 08 and the regular project copy and pasted.
- Made sure **Global.asax** is in the folder.

Here is my current Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {




        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "User", action = "LogIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Root",
          "",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );



    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }
}
```

Here is a part of my Web.config:

```
    <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

I'm pretty desperate at this point because I've wasted almost 3 days in this, and my only possible solution at this point seems to rewrite the code to a regular ASP.NET web app, not MVC.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Tried also registering correct asp.net version with IIS (aspnet_regiis.exe)?

Comment: Yeah, ASP.NET 4.0 is installed, didn't work either :(

Comment: I couldn't find a solution to the problem, so I had to rewrite the page to a normal ASP.NET web page, thankfully it wasn't a very big page. If I had known setting up IIS 7.5 with a ASP.NET MVC app was such a pain in the ass I would have stuck to regular ASP.NET. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: Ya, IIS and MVC is a real nightmare.  I'm spending the same amount of time dealing with the problem you are, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a lot of things, but my first guess for you would be be to check your map route statement.

Just keep this in your RegisterRoute statement and see if that fixes it.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I remove that statement and it works.  When I keep it in the routing attributes stop working

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by add this lines in project.json

```
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "Views",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]
```

},

Comment: My issue was the same - I was pulling in some html from a special folder, and the published site had the appearance of not working with a particular route- but the problem was behind the scenes as the published site didn't include the necessary folder for my view. Adding the name of it in the "include" of the json fixed the issue.